# tar --files-from complains "Cannot stat: No such file or directory"

Tags: linux, tar, stat

When I type:

```
tar -cvf ~/changeset.tar --files-from ~/changeset.txt
```

it responds with this output:

```
tar:  admin/memberinformation.php            : Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar:  business/clsPreferredAgencies.php      : Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar:  business/clsPreferredAgencies_test.php : Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar:  business/clscustomer.php               : Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar:  business/clsfeedback.php               : Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar:  business/clsleads.php                  : Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar:  business/connection.php                : Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar:  crons/daily_activity.php               : Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar:  crons/not_closed_orders2.php           : Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar:  crons/unaccepted_orders2.php           : Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar:  js/jquery-1.4.2.js                     : Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar:  sql/alter-project.sql                  : Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar:  sql/buyerName.php                      : Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar:  sql/preferredAgencies.sql              : Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar:  sql/underwriters_list.sql              : Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar:  user/close_selectedporject.php         : Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar:  user/feedback.php                      : Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar:  user/forum.php                         : Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar:  user/initiatelead.php                  : Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar:  user/leadprocess_detail.php            : Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar:  user/mem_direc.php                     : Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar:  user/qws.php                           : Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar:  user/view_leaddetails.php              : Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar:  user/viewfeedbackforusers.php          : Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar:  user/viewfeedbacks.php                 : Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors
lsiden@lsiden2:~/titan$ ls admin/memberinformation.php 
admin/memberinformation.php
```

[Here are the contents of ~/changeset.txt](http://pastie.org/1071084). In other words, a bunch of relative paths.  As a sanity check:

```
$ ls admin/memberinformation.php 
admin/memberinformation.php
```

Why can't tar find any of these files even though they are clearly reachable from the current directory with the relative paths given?

FYI:

```
$ tar --version
tar (GNU tar) 1.15.1
```

Answer (score 5):

You have an extra space at the beginning of each line in `changeset.txt`.

**EDIT**: Also, did you by any chance create `changeset.txt` on a Windows machine? If so, there may be an extra `^M` character at the end of each line. Most unix programs will consider this character to be part of the line (here, part of the file name), whereas Windows considers the `^M` part of the newline sequence. You can see whether this is the case by running `cat -A changeset.txt`: normally there should just be a `$` at the end of each line; if you see `^M$`, you have a Windows file. The `dos2unix` command is often available to convert the line endings.

Comment: I tried to remove the extra space but it still wouldn't work.  I finally had to do "tar cvf myfile.tar `cat mystuff`" instead of "-T mystuff"

Comment: @Larry: before I noticed the extra spaces, I thought of Windows line endings (see my edit); could it have been both problems?

Answer (score 1):

on ubuntu 10.04, `tar --files-from` or `-T` options

when a the last line contains space, tar failed. If you add a blank line at the end , it's run.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem on my Mac (Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0)

It turned out that two of the lines in my file.txt had an extra whitespace at the end of the line.  Once I deleted the whitespace at the end of the lines, it worked fine. I confirmed this by re-adding a whitespace to the end of a line and it failed with an error stating:

> Cannot stat: No such file or directory

So it appears that an extra whitespace anywhere or an extra blank line will cause a failure.

Also, FWIW, I was able to specify a file that contained either of the following:

```
./src/com/blarg/foo.java
```

or

```
src/com/blarg/foo.java
```

so either way was okay.  it's just that pesky whitespace that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely tar would love to be noticed about the current path. So instead of

```
admin/memberinformation.php
```

the changeset.txt should read

```
./admin/memberinformation.php
```

or alternatively contain the full path.

Comment: `admin/memberinformation.php` and `./admin/memberinformation.php` both work if the current working dir is the same that contains the files and both will not work if it is not the dir containing the files

Comment: The currend dir indeed contains the files.  Even when I removed the extra spaces, it didn't work.  I finally had to take a different approach that I mentioned in the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by running:

```
tar cvf ~/changeset.tar `cat ../changeset.txt`
```

Comment: This might work in your case but realy does not bring any insight into your actual problem .. pretty useless as you mix up relative and absulute path without telling us about the diectory structure. -1 sorry.